# Node js date неизвестный формат

Tags: javascript, node.js, дата, express, mongoose

Приложение написано на express js, для роботы с базой mongodb использую mongoose и плагин mongoose-ttl для удаление старых записей из базы. Есть модель:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ttl = require('mongoose-ttl');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/botSC");


var testSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    genre: Array
});

testSchema.plugin(ttl, { ttl: '1m' });
exports.Test = connection.model('Test', testSchema);
```

server.js

```
var Test = require('../models/test').Test;
module.exports = function (passport) {

    router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
        new Test({title: "hello", ttl: '2s', interval: "5s"}).save(function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            var date = new Date();
            res.send(date);
        })
    });
    return router;
};
```

В базу сохраняется такая запись:

```
{
  "_id": "572078bc37eac5bc1f13bf26",
  "title": "hello",
  "__ttl": "2016-04-27T08:30:54.762Z",
  "genre": [],
  "__v": 0
}
```

На страницу выводится такая дата:

```
"2016-04-27T08:30:52.764Z"
```

Но должно записать и вывести такую дату:

```
Wed Apr 27 2016 11:30:53 GMT+0300 (Финляндия (лето))
```

В чем может быть причина получения даты -3ч и в непонятном формате?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что при отправке объекта из express, он преобразует его к строке через `JSON.stringify()`, который при передаче `Date` в качестве аргумента вернет как раз строку вида `"2016-04-27T08:30:52.764Z"`. Данная строка - строка времени в часовом поясе UTC. Чтобы получить дату в локальном часовом поясе достаточно передать эту строку в конструктор `new Date(JSON.parse(date))`. `JSON.parse()` необходим (если только клиент, получающий ответ не выполняет преобразование JSON-строки в объект), т.к. при строковом преобразовании, результат будет строкой, содержащей кавычки, т.е. строка будет вида `'"2016-04-27T12:37:18.443Z"'`.
Если строку локального времени необходимо предать на клиент в отформатированном виде, можно использовать метод `date.toString()`.

Comment: Понятно. Но почему разница в 3 часа. console.log(new Date() выводит  Wed Apr 27 2016 11:30:53 GMT+0300 (Финляндия (лето))  а res.send(new Date())    выводит  "2016-04-27T08:30:53.764Z"

Comment: Z в конце строки даты указывает на то, что дата отображена в UTC, т.е. без смещения по часовому поясу. console.log неявно выполняет toString(), который возвращает время с учетом часового пояса

Comment: В общем, в датах разницы нет, это один и тот же момент времени, просто отображенный в разных часовых зонах